# Accessing asset in Watson Studio notebook (.log file) using 'with open' and 'project-lib'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, watson-studio, project-lib

I'm trying to deploy a working python 3.6 notebook in Watson Studio (cloud). However I'm struggling to access files/assets.
After uploading a .log file to my assets, I want to open and process it using

```
with open(project.get_file('messages.log'), 'r') as file:
```

the error message returns

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

Apart from telling me how to open/read the log-file, I'd also appreciate a short explanation on why project.get_file returns a BytesIo object.

Answer (score 0):

*project-lib*'s function *get_file* reads the file from your Watson Studio project's storage.
You can read your file like this:

```
buffer = project.get_file('messages.log')
log_file = buffer.getvalue()
```

I am not hundred percent sure why it has been decided to return a BytesIo object but it is quite convenient e.g. if you want to read your data into a pandas dataframe:

```
my_file = project.get_file('myFile.csv')
my_file.seek(0)
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(my_file, nrows=10)
```

You can find `project-lib`'s documentation here: [project-lib for Python](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/project-lib-python.html)

Comment: Thanks Simone. Unfortunately this isn't working as it should. Although the object log_file is being created, it is empty. Also, note that I'm trying to use the function open, which leads to the described error. I could convert the bytes object into a string object (which I have done), but in any case, the object is empty/does not contain the log info.